# RxJS asynchronous loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous, angular, rxjs

We are doing some prototype testing where we take a json which has around 28000 records via http. We convert it to an instance of a class in Typescript and add it to an existing array.

The array is then bind to the view which re and displays the list.

```
this.http.get("http://localhost:8100/list.son")
            .map((res) => res.json())
            .flatMap((array, index) => array).
            .subscribe((value:any) => {
                    console.log("RENDERING");
                    this.list.push(new Element(8, value.name, value.number));
                  });
```

The problem is that the flatmap seems to be passing in elements of the array one by one to the subscribe function synchronously (tried using a set timeout before the http call which only ran after the subscribe). Therefore it is a sort of a loop of 28000 elements which hangs the UI thread. How could we trigger subscribe on an interval basis so that the UI thread can get some time during the processing of the list elements. (Essentially pseudo async recursion).

**EDIT : Updated code with Meir's answer**

Here is the code that I have currently, additionally I believe map is the wrong operation since it outputs the number of inputs it takes in. So correct me if I am wrong it takes in one http response and outputs one array, and therefore this array is processed as a whole by the rest of the steps. Additionally I have provided the sample list.json.

```
this.http.get("http://localhost:8100/list.json")
                .map((res) => {
                  console.log(res.json().list);
                  return res.json().list
                })
                .delayWhen((v) => Observable.timer(50))
                .buffer(Observable.timer(50, 50))
                .subscribe((entry) => {
                  console.log("CAME HERE AA " + entry);
                });
```

LIST JSON, there are more entries but I just kept it at two here

```
{ "list" : [
  {
    "name" : "test",
    "number" : "that",
    "verificationId" : 78
  },
  {
    "name" : "test",
    "number" : "that",
    "verificationId" : 78
  },
  {
    "name" : "test",
    "number" : "that",
    "verificationId" : 78
  },
  {
    "name" : "test",
    "number" : "that",
    "verificationId" : 78
  }]
}
```

Comment: Why do you use flatMap and not simply map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chunk it either by chunk size or time, for time chunks use:

```
source.buffer(Rx.Observable.timer(250, 250))
   .subscribe(chunk => {
     console.log('chunk ', chunk);
     list1.splice(list1.length, 0, ...chunk);
});
```

A working [jsbin sample](http://jsbin.com/basogu/edit?html,js,console) with both cases.

Comment: Almost there, just stuck with one more thing. When using it with a http call how do I process the response, convert it to a json array and pass it on to delayWhen for chunking. I tried simply prepending the "this.http.get("http://localhost:8100/list.son")
            .map((res) => res.json())" to your example but subscribe was not even then reached

Comment: Can you post the full code? I suspect your http call has no subscription at its end so it stays cold. In general: `this.http.get(...).map(...).subscribe(...)`

Comment: Updated the main question with the code sample. Here the subscribe is reached (I can't remember the one where it was cold since I was changing it a lot), however entry is null and nothing is printed in console.log

Comment: Why do you need the flatMap?

Comment: Used flatmap so that subscribe was called per the number of elements in the array returned by the json, so without looping I can process the array, so when there were 200 elements subscribe would be called 200 times. Though the problem was that was synchronous. Also did you have a look at the second edit sample (which does not use flatMap) which is what I created after your answer.

Comment: Now I looked, sorry, the previous answer was using my phone.
So let me make sure I get it right, you have a call that returns all values in one array, this array is long so the rendering "chocks" so you want to break it to chunks. To do so you convert it to a sequence and group them every few elements?

Comment: Yes more or less, also after I break it into chunks the rest of the processing MUST be asynchronous so that other events in the event loop can be processed as well

Comment: On the other hand, if you need view responsiveness, you can use a slice pipe, starting with a small number (say 10-20 items) which is enough to populate the entire view and after other events were processed, display all elements